# How to increase upload speed above your limit

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, speed, upload

I just got a new 16mbps internet. The download speed is good, 14mbps but the upload speed is terrible, its 0.8mbps. I asked my ISP about it and he said that that was the max speed could go. I made some research online about upload and I found out that in the cable there "is more room for download than upload". When I do a speedtest it goes like 1mpbs for 1 for 3 seconds and it goes down to 0.8 mbps again. Now I know thet you cant get more internet than your ISP gives you(unless u hack it), but can I "make more room" for upload, like decrease download to increase upload?

Update: Speed test at speedtest.net by ookla shows like 1.2mpbs and imediately goes down, but in https://www.speedcheck.org/ , which was a longer test it stayed at 1.2mbps. My first anwser here told me that my ISP uses program to limit my speed the moment it detects it goes above the limit=. now here is my other question: does https://www.speedcheck.org/ anything to bypass that program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is simply not possible.

Upload and download speeds are assigned by the ISP. They have full control over what you get, and there is no way to change this unless you pay them money and the line is physically capable of achieving the speeds.

So if the ISP tells you you cannot go faster, then this is usually due to a contract you have with them. You pay them money for a connection that has a download and upload speed attached to it, and they must give you a speed that is at least 80% of what they promise.

If your speed is 16 mbit down and 1 mbit up, then reaching 14 mbit down and 0.8 mbit up is a good connection, and there is nothing you can do to change this.

If the ISP has more speeds to choose from (and you pay more), you can consider upgrading your connection to a faster speed and pay more for it. If that is not an option, then you are stuck with what you currently have.

It is possible to look at concurrent ISP's to see if they offer a higher upload speed for a reasonable price, but again, if it appears that you are stuck with the current connection for whatever reason, you will in no way be able to change your up and download speeds.

You wonder how you can get that initial high speed, this is the ISP capping your connection the moment they detect a high-speed transfer. This is in their rights to do, and there is nothing you can do to change this behavior. There is a software limiter active that has a tiny delay before it registers that you go above the limit, and then caps your transfer. It is designed in such way that you cannot get faster speeds consistently.

Comment: I asked because first I wanted a DSLT connecton 30mbps , but my ISP said the even if you connect it you will not get the speed because my house was 1km far from the sharing center, so I was forced to connect with ADSL. But he only two options is ADSL was 8mbps and 16 mbps, and the upload was the same speed, so unfortunately I cannot get faster speed even if I pay more.

Comment: Part of the initial "1mbps for 3 seconds" would be outgoing buffers filling up on the computer and router. Those buffers are the reason we do longer tests, in order to get an average speed rather than bursty/buffered speeds. The actual line speed doesn't change, but buffers filling up between your computer and the ADSL line can make it *seem* momentarily faster.

Comment: LPChip Update: Speed test at speedtest.net by ookla shows like 1.2mpbs and imediately goes down, but in https://www.speedcheck.org/ , which was a longer test it stayed at 1.2mbps. You told me that my ISP uses program to limit my speed the moment it detects it goes above the limit. now here is my other question: does https://www.speedcheck.org/ anything to bypass that program? Or speedtest.net send data to test the wifi and the ISP slows it down and speedchech.org just measures the wifi speed without sending data?

Comment: As others have said, it's a built-in limitation you'll have to live with. No hack or trick on your PC or home router will bring you more juice than what your (copper) line can offer. The bottleneck doesn't reside in your appartment, but at the DSLAM where you line starts. The "A" in ADSL means Asynchronous, which means you get more speed on the downlink than on the uplink.

Comment: @ador007 it is possible the server at speedtest.net is causing issues and thus not capable of doing faster speed sustained, or that it throttles somehow.